# Bunion (hallux valgus) surgery - is there a procedure w/out cutting and/or stitching / tighning / fixing bones together?

Tags: orthopedics

Some orthopedic doctors claim bunions are mostly due to footwear, some from heredity, some "jury is out on this one". But as far as I've watched surgeries, doctors talks, all are concerned with recurrence and as far as I understand, that is why all major types of procedures (osteotomy, lapidus, stitching rope between 1st and 2nd metatarsal (MT)) aim for mitigation of that risk.

But if one want to test hypothesis of footwear, then just fixing (e.i. reducing) intermetatarsal angle (IMA) by moving 1st MT like in lapidus might be enough provided a patient is ready to commit to proper shoes, isn't it? In one "lecture" I recall it was said there are more than 100 procedures. Is there and if yes how is it called the surgical procedure where 1st MT is just moved toward 2nd MT?

Comment: I'm unsure of what you're asking and part of the reason is you're using acronyms without spelling them out first. By MT you mean metatarsal joint? How could moving a joint not involve surgery?

Comment: @Carey Gregory, I see your point, just that it relations to bunions IMA and MT are rather certain, I think I'll spell them out anyway. I'm not asking for conservative here, though some argue it is an option. Lapiplasty moves metatarsal (MT) using a "clamp", but also fuses MT with cuneiform, I'm looking for move-only procedure.